# Input tag does not show the value of textbox when it is in small device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I shrink the web page, input box does show its value. `input` tag's  `value` does not show when it is in small device.The full code is below. It is a basic table having 3 rows.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="table-responsive hidden-xs">
                <table class="table table-hover">

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Ürün</th>
                            <th>Adet</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Toplam</th>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                                <div class="media">
                                    <a class="img-thumbnail pull-left" href="#"><img class="media-object img-product-cart" src="~/Content/images/kitap/kitap2.jpg" /></a>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="#">Matematik</a></h4>
                                        <h5 class="media-heading">Yazar: Halil Kan</h5>
                                        <h5 class="media-heading">ISBN: 1234567897</h5>
                                        <h5 class="media-heading"><strong>Adet Fiyatı:  45.23 TL</strong></h5>
                                        <span>Durum:</span><span class="text-success"><strong>Stokta 10 adet var.</strong></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>

                            <td class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="3"/>
                            </td>

                            <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong>135.36 TL</strong></td>

                            <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Kaldır
                                </button>
                            </td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-sm-8 col-md-8"> </td>
                            <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1"> </td>
                            <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1"><h4>Kargo Ücreti</h4><h3>Toplam</h3></td>
                            <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-right"><h5><strong>3.99 TL</strong></h5><h3>123.12 TL</h3></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-sm-8 col-md-8"> </td>
                            <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1"> </td>
                            <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Alişverişe Devam
                                </button>
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
                                    Ödeme Sayfasına Geç <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>


                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sometimes `col-*-1` is just too narrow to show the content. Use a wider unit such as `col-*-2`.

Comment: remove hidden-xs class I can't see anything in small devices

Comment: <td class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" value="3"/>
 </td> It is already 2

Comment: I dont want to show it in xs devices. @neophyte

Comment: Sorry, then sometimes `col-*-2` is too narrow. Perhaps you should consider letting some of the columns stack vertically sooner.

Answer (score 0):

[Bootply link](http://www.bootply.com/OzfbuK60qg) seems to work fine for small devices.

according to defination

> Extra small devices Phones (<768px) - .col-xs-
>
> Small devices Tablets (≥768px) - .col-sm-
>
> Medium devices Desktops (≥992px) - .col-md-
>
> Large devices Desktops (≥1200px) - .col-lg-

So it works fine for device size `Small devices Tablets (≥768px) - .col-sm-`

hope this helps!